# How to install a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, scroll

I'm trying to install this **[jQuery Smooth Div Scroll](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/)** plugin on my website and I can't get it to work. My goal is to get a horizontal list of links that scrolls to either the left or right when hovered over (depending on cursor position).

I added the following files to my HTML:

```
<script src="js/jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.3-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.kinetic.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"
```

I also added this right before the closing /body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
        mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
        manualContinuousScrolling: true,
        autoScrollingMode: "onStart"
    });
});
</script>
```

I have this set of links:

```
<div class="topics_panel">
    <div class="table" id="makeMeScrollable">
        <a href="/index.php?q=News&search=search" class="topic" id="news">News</a>
        <a href="/index.php?q=Cars&search=search" class="topic" id="cars">Cars</a>
        <a href="/index.php?q=Food&search=search" class="topic" id="food">Food</a>
        <a href="/index.php?q=Sports&search=search" class="topic" id="sports">Sports</a>
        <a href="/index.php?q=Travel&search=search" class="topic" id="travel">Travel</a>
        <a href="/index.php?q=Technology&search=search" class="topic" id="tech">Technology</a>
        <a href="/index.php?q=Arts&search=search" class="topic" id="arts">Arts</a>
        <a href="/index.php?q=Architecture&search=search" class="topic" id="architecture">Architecture</a>
        <a href="/index.php?q=Entertainment&search=search" class="topic" id="entertainment">Entertainment</a>
        <a href="/index.php?q=Music&search=search" class="topic" id="music">Music</a>
        <a href="/index.php?q=Money&search=search" class="topic" id="money">Money</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get this set of links to be a scrolling horizontal list like I mentioned above. However, all I get when I try to preview it is the plain horizontal list with no animation whatsoever so the jQuery part obviously isn't working.

I also added this to my CSS:

```
#makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea *
{
    position: relative;
    display: block
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* If you don't want the images in the scroller to be selectable, try the following
        block of code. It's just a nice feature that prevent the images from
        accidentally becoming selected/inverted when the user interacts with the scroller. */
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

When I preview my code this is what I get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqcfo.png

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong? I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: You have to load the plugins AFTER you load `jquery.min.js`.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't load two versions of `jquery-ui`.

Comment: Aren't you getting errors in the Javascript console warning that `$` or `jQuery` aren't defined?

Comment: Follow the order of plugin loading like how they have it in the demo [https://github.com/tkahn/Smooth-Div-Scroll/blob/master/index.html](https://github.com/tkahn/Smooth-Div-Scroll/blob/master/index.html)